# How to set default indentation to Tabs in WebStorm

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

How do you set default indentation preference to `Tabs` and not `Spaces` in WebStorm?

I know you can edit the indentation when you select lines of code, but where do you edit the default setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Preferences, then Go to Editor > Code style > Select a language > "Use tab character"

[image: Seen here]